# Ноутбук на ubuntu 19.04 не работает

Tags: linux, ноутбук

Я оставлял ноутбук в спящем режиме, около 7 дней. Его ОС linux 19. Когда включаю ноутбук, он не загружается и не могу работать на нём как . Попробовал переустановить с флешки линукс, но флешку ноутбук не видит. Как мне исправить это? Подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: что такое linux 19?

Comment: Может он ... разрядился?

Comment: Он постоянно подключён к зарядке

Comment: *Как мне исправить это?" - что **это**? Вы не дали абсолютно **никакой** информации для анализа, кроме некоего "Linux-19", не существующего в природе... Логи, сообщения об ошибках, что у Вас есть ?

Comment: Дико извиняюсь, Сергей спасибо за правки. ОС ubuntu 19.04 или disco dingo. Я пишу с телефона и не получается загрузить фото, но показывается сообщение по типу : [ OK ] Started Message of the Day , [ ОК ] Started CUPS Scheduler. И так далее...

Comment: Я думаю, вам на ноуте нужна винда.

Comment: "флешку ноутбук не видит", а меню загрузки открывается? Выбор устройства для загрузки.

Comment: BIOS имеете в виду ? Да в нём магу войти, но даже если флешка должна загрузится первой, то она этого не делает